# Showing Wronskian determinant equals zero for nonconstant holomorphic functions implies dependence

Tags: complex-analysis

In my complex analysis class this term, I am given the following problem:

Let $G$ be a domain (open and simply connected), let $f,g: G \to \mathbb{C}$ be nonconstant holomorphic functions on $G$ with

$\begin{vmatrix}
f & g \\
f' & g'\notag
\end{vmatrix} = 0$

i.e. the Wronskian determinant of the functions is equal to zero. I am to show that the functions are linearly dependent, i.e. there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $ag(x) + bf(x) = 0$ $\forall x \in G$.

Then there is a small remark and the end of the exercise that this claim only holds in general for complex functions; there exist functions, for example, in $C^1$ such that this claim does not hold.

At first  glance, I asked myself why the solution isn't simply that since the determinant of the matrix is equal to zero for all x, we can simply conclude that the two columns of the matrix must be linearly dependent and therefore $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent. However, nothing about this proposed solution answers why this doesn't hold in general for real functions.

What am I wrongly concluding? Why does the argument about the linear dependence of the column vectors not work since it would also imply the same for differentiable real functions?

Answer (score 1):

The columns are linearly dependent for each value of $x$, but they can have different coefficients for linearly dependence for different $x$.

A simple example is $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x |x|$, then$f'(x)=2x$ and $g'(x)=2|x|$

so the Wronskian is $2x^2|x|-2x(x|x|)=0$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$.

But you cannot have $a,b$ such that $af(x)+bg(x)=0$ for all $x$.
It comes down to the fact that $f(x)=g(x)$ when $x\geq 0$, and $f(x)=-g(x)$ for $x<0$. So that the columns of Wronskian are indeed linear dependent (for each $x$ only).

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the problem! I knew when I asked this question there would be a very simple obvious answer that I was not considering. So then the trick in this problem is to show that for complex functions the coefficients for linear dependence are the same for all z in G?

Comment: @JocelynFranzen Yes, you may need to consider Taylor series of $f,g$